# making microsoft word buttons inside document that can run javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf, ms-office, office-js

Is it possible to create buttons inside a word document that can run JavaScript code? somewhat similar to running VBA code like:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    MsgBox "hello world"
End Sub
```

I want to make a button that will still work after the document is exported as a PDF. Like in this tutorial: http://www.lystech.com/webhelp/Content/calculate-in-pdf/
They are using CenoPDF, but I was hoping to find another way to do this on my own. I tried reading about Office JavaScript API, but couldn't find something relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Embedding scripts to a native object is not supported via. Office-js. If you are looking for cross-app scenarios (Word and PDF), I don't think it's possible through the JavaScript solutions that Office-js/add-ins offer. I can't think of an alternate solution either.

Comment: It is definitely possible to create an add-in that does that like CenoPDF, but I was hoping to find an easier way. I guess the easiest way would be to buy CenoPDF. Thanks any way for the insights.